# How can I write a Rust macro and what type should I use?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have an implementation for a struct that needs to be implemented on multiple structs with an argument for every struct.

My impl statement is as follows:

```rust
#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for ReadMe {
    type Error = AuthErrors;

    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let db = request
            .guard::<&State<mongodb::Database>>()
            .await
            .expect("No database state!");
        let token = request.headers().get_one("Authorization");

        match token {
            Some(token) => {
                // check validity
                let user = get_user_by_token(token.to_string(), db.inner().to_owned()).await;

                match user {
                    Some(user) => {
                        if user.tokenData.scopes.split(" ").any(|x| x == "ReadMe") {
                            Outcome::Success(ReadMe(Some(BasicScope {
                                user: user.user,
                                value: true,
                            })))
                        } else {
                            Outcome::Failure((Status::Forbidden, AuthErrors::ScopeMissing))
                        }
                    }
                    None => Outcome::Failure((Status::Unauthorized, AuthErrors::Invalid)), // TODO?: Should this return something else?
                }
            }
            None => Outcome::Failure((Status::Unauthorized, AuthErrors::Missing)),
        }
    }
}
```

The reason this would benefit from being a macro is that I will have a lot of structs that need a slightly modified version of that implementation (`"ReadMe"` has to be different for every struct). Instead of copy and pasting this implementation, each one being slightly modified it would be cleaner to do `#[derive(Scope("ReadMe"))]`.

How could this be transformed in to a macro I can reuse?

Comment: You should elaborate on your requirements here, as is I'm not seeing what part of this would benefit from translation to a macro. Maybe include a second example to indicate what code would be duplicated and what would differ? (Try to simplify it if you can, minimal reproducible example and all.)

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks! Ive updated my question to include the differences and explain why it would benefit from being a macro.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the only difference between implementations is a `&str` then you could just write a function `from_request_and_str(request: &'r Request<'_>, readme_name: &str))` and delegate to that. If the following code should be different too, you could add another argument of type `impl Fn() -> ReadMe` or whatever you need. Generally speaking, you should consider a non-macro solution before going down that rabbit-hole.

Comment: @rodrigo The implementation is used by a framework (Rocket) which is out of my control and because of that that won’t work sadly

Comment: Maybe you could add two different implementations of your would-be generated code, so that we can see what code is duplicated and what code is different?